# Gerando relatorio com ReportViewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Como é possivel gerar um relatorio de um objeto e suas dependencias em Report Viewer com C#? 
tenho uma classe Carro, onde cada Carro tem seus Modelos. Consigo exibir um relatorio com os Carros e os Modelos separados, mas como faço para ficarem

```
Modelo1
  Carro1
  Carro2
Modelo2
  Carro1
  Carro2
Modelo3
  Carro1
```

Como faço essa ligação para vincular os carros pertencentes ao modelo? sabendo que na classe Carro eu tenho um atributo que contém o código do modelo.

Comment: Relacionado: http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2017/03/15/como-utilizar-o-report-viewer-no-visual-studio-2017/ e http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2010/10/09/agrupamentos-simples-no-report-viewer-do-vs-2010/ um ensina instalar e o outro ensina a fazer o grupo.

Comment: Olá Virgilio, já havia visto essas video aulas e infelizmente elas não atendem o que eu quero fazer. eu tenho duas classes separadas e não uma unica classe com todos os dados, logo é carregado meu report através de 2 datatables modelo e carro, e eu queria no proprio relatorio vincular eles, também não utilizo uma table mas sim uma list, será que seria o mesmo procedimento? obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Você pode fazer uma ViewModel juntar as informações com Linq e.mostrar os dados eu reproduzi e funcionou. Ou seja atende sim o que você precisa... Da onde vem essas classes, voce utiliza ORM ???

Comment: Esse foi um exemplo básico para eu ter uma ideia de como fazer ... a minha duvida seria um pouco mais complicada ... veja que na pergunta eu especifico que queria uma ligação para vincular os carros pertencentes ao modelo ... pra ficar de fácil entendimento a todos, porém na minha aplicação eu trabalho com contas / parcelas ... onde uma conta tem 0 ou muitas parcelas ... minha necessidade seria criar um relatório que exibisse todas as contas a vista e no caso se elas focem a prazo exibissem as parcelas ... acho que não deixei claro o suficiente na minha pergunta "/

Comment: Mas talvez eu consiga fazer isso com essa sua solução, eu utilizo uma DAO normal, onde eu faço um select. acho que poderia fazer um select de tudo isso e jogar em uma view, e onde a conta é a vista eu coloria um if na aplicação para que não fosse necessario exibir as parcelas. mas como faço isso? como vinculo duas tabelas e faço um if para aparecer ou não uma determinada tabela?

Comment: Eu fiz um exemplo esta no pc agora estou no celular depois eu posto

Comment: Certo! Estou no aguardo, obrigado pela ajuda